# Sort data in one text file and save it into another text file as csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have data obtained from a serial port as shown below

```
A0:2.86
A1:1.51
A2:2.84
A3:1.51
A4:2.86
A0:2.87
A1:1.51
A2:2.84
A3:1.51
A4:2.86
A0:2.86
A1:1.51
A2:2.85
```

How can I sort the data received in the previous text files into different text file as shown in the examples below? Thanks.

```
Text file containing A0                Text file containing A1
2.86, 1                                1.51, 1
2.86, 2                                1.50, 2
2.87, 3                                1.51, 3

Text file containing A2                Text file containing A3
2.85, 1                                1.51, 1
2.86, 2                                1.51, 2
2.84, 3                                1.51, 3
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried something yourself or are you starting from scratch?

Comment: @Stefano.Maff I am starting from scratch and I have no idea where do I start from. Any kind of help would be a great help for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do some manipulations on your data. The code below will organize it as you need, you'll just need to write it to a file (named after `k`) with it's values.

```
text = '''
A0:2.86
A1:1.51
A2:2.84
A3:1.51
A4:2.86
A0:2.87
A1:1.51
A2:2.84
A3:1.51
A4:2.86
A0:2.86
A1:1.51
A2:2.85'''

text_list = text.split('\n')

for ele in text_list:
    k, v = ele.split(':')
    ls = d.setdefault(k, [])
    ls.append(v)

for k, v in d.items():
    print k, v

A1 ['1.51', '1.51', '1.51']
A0 ['2.86', '2.87', '2.86']
A3 ['1.51', '1.51']
A2 ['2.84', '2.84', '2.85']
A4 ['2.86', '2.86']
```

Comment: Could I change the the text = ''' '''' to text = open("message1.txt", 'r') as I have more than the data I have shown in the question above saved in a text file named message1.txt. Would it yield the same result?

Comment: Thanks Vinny I shall try it once I am back home :D